# Pass parameters to bash file in the middle of a java code

Tags: java, c++, linux, bash

I have a Java code running by the following command line

```
java -jar CPM-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar Example arg[0] arg[1] arg[2] arg[3]
```

clearly I need to pass 4 parameters.

In the middle of my Java code, I should call a C++ code using the following bash file.

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/CPM/Codes/source/GcEqClass arg[0]
```

arg[0] in the bash file is same as arg[0] in Java command line and the main reason to have arg[0] in command line is to use it in bash script. My question, how can I pass arg[0] from the command line to the bash script without editing the bash file manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bash file should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/CPM/Codes/source/GcEqClass "$@"
```

`"$@"` is basically equivalent to the the argument array in java, and similar to `"$1" "$2" "$3" ..`

From Java, you can then do:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { 
    "/yourpath/toyour/script", arg[0]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

write the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar CPM-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar Example $1 $2 $3 $4
```

save it as say `scritp.sh`, then run it :

```
./script.sh 1 2 3 4
```